# How do I create a frequency distribution?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a frequency distribution to show how many customers have transacted 1x, 2x, 3x, etc.

I have a database `transactions` and column `user_id`. Each row indicates a transaction, and if a user_id shows up in multiple rows, that user has done multiple transactions.

Now I'd like to get a list that looks something like this:

```
Tra.  | Freq.
0     | 345 
1     | 543 
2     | 45 
3     | 20 
4     | 0 
5     | 3 
etc
```

Currently I have this, but it just shows a list of users and how many transactions they have had.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as number_of_transactions
FROM transactions
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY number_of_transactions DESC;
```

I did some digging and was suggested that `generate_series` might help, but I'm stuck and don't know how to move forward.

Comment: Hint: what you need is the frequencies of frequencies. (you'll need an extra layer of aggregation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first result as input to an outer query where you apply the count again, but this time grouping on number_of_transactions:

```
SELECT number_of_transactions, COUNT(*) AS freq 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as number_of_transactions
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_id
) A
GROUP BY number_of_transactions;
```

This would transform a result like:

```
user_id     number_of_transactions
----------- ----------------------
1           2
2           1
3           2
4           4
```

to this:

```
number_of_transactions freq
---------------------- -----------
1                      1
2                      2
4                      1
```

Comment: Thanks @jpw, this worked perfectly and I learned something new about inner and outer queries!

Comment: @SiamChoudhury Happy to have helped :)